# Win 10, python 3.8 selenium 3.141 WebDriver error: Message: chrome not reachable

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I searched a bunch of questions beforehand. None could solve my problem.
I simply want to open a webpage and click "Download" button. But, I am stuck at the opening the page itself. I am using python 3.8 with PyCharm Edu 2020. My Chrome and Chrome driver Version are both 81.xx and I use Selenium 3.141. My Code is as below:

```
cd_path = r'C:/Users/path to/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = cd_path)
driver.get(merged.Link[1])
```

I have a dataframe consists of links where I want to open those links row by row and click "Download". But, all I get is the error below:

```
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\path to pycharm project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\spath to pycharm project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\path to pycharm project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

Does anyone knows how can I open an actual Chrome page not the one that says "Chrome is being controlled with the automated test software"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get your correct driver with

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

if you don't have it installed :

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

This package will handle all the manual complications of finding the correct driver.